# The function get(String, any, Function) is undefined for the type Function jquery

Tags: jquery, get

I don't understand what is the problem with my code since i saw it in many tutorials just the same. Pls help.... Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#div').click(function() {
type: 'POST';
String url= 'fivepluscms/client/CMSGallery.jsp';
String data = $('a').attr('id');
String equalPosition = data.indexOf('='); //Get the position of '='
String number = data.substring(equalPosition + 1);
$.get(url, number, function(raspuns){
  $('#div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail"').html(raspuns);
});
});
});
```

Comment: There's no need to define a type of a variable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you _didn't_ see this in many tutorials, not if they were JavaScript (or jQuery) tutorials. In JS you use `var` to declare variables, not `String`. I'm not sure what you _intended_ with `type: 'POST';`, but what you _got_ was a pointless label (`type:`) followed by a pointless expression (`'POST'`).

Comment: so I deleted the type post because you were right it wasn't in it's place but still nothing...

Comment: The `type:'POST';` wouldn't actually cause an error, it just wouldn't do anything. Did you change each `String` to `var`? And have you included jquery.js in your page?

Comment: I changed the string type to var and included the jquery.js

Comment: i don't know how but it works the error is still there but the script works...Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('#div').click(function() {

           var url= 'fivepluscms/client/CMSGallery.jsp';
           var data = $('a').attr('id'); //means the id of the first 'a' //probably incorrect
           var equalPosition = data.indexOf('='); //Get the position of '='
           var number = data.substring(equalPosition + 1);

           $.get(url, number, function(raspuns){
              $('div.ngg-gallery-thumbnail').html(raspuns);
    });
    });
    });
```

Comment: still have the error and got another one:The function $(HTMLDocument) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.get(url, { number: number }, function(raspuns){
  $('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail').html(raspuns);
});
```

Your problem is that the second variable is not an array, when it needs to be. You can see this here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: no it still won't work....now i get:The function get(String, ___anonymous350_366, Function) is undefined

Comment: The second parameter can be a string or an object (what the jQuery doco calls a "map").